# Unpack .xz file within C code

Tags: c, xz

My question is quite simple. Is there any possible way to unpack packed .xz file in from C code? I would probably call some default linux-integrated program to unpack it for me, but how exactly does it work? I call the external function and than somehow I get directly back to the program content of the extracted file? Let's say that inside the .xz file is text file and I want to read it afterwards.

Comment: check system() api http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html

Comment: The [`xzutils`](http://tukaani.org/xz/) download comes with documentation and sample code: http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/examples/02_decompress.c;hb=e7b424d267a34803db8d92a3515528be2ed45abd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `system("xz -dl file.xz")`, but there is good info here and links to source code to implementations:
http://tukaani.org/xz/format.html

Comment: Also a great way of introducing parameter injection vulnerabilities. (Don't use `system()` for any code you actually have other people execute.)

Comment: Yes, like always, you want to understand what you are doing if you want to have a secure system. And system() is not particularly secure...

Comment: moreover, your are supposing `system` can execute a command and that the command (xz) exists on the machine... I would go definitively with the use of a library (which becomes a normal dependency for the software if you do not include it)

Comment: I have done some research about `system` and I found function popen. As is in python. Wouldn't that be better?

Comment: @Jendas In terms of security? By far.

Comment: Maybe, it really depends on what you want to achieve in the end. If all you want to do is read the file, yes. But if you want to do something else, e.g. "change the word X to word Y" in the file, it's not as useful. But then if you just want to read it for simple purposes, why do you need a C program in the first place? Surely a shell script is easier [or some python?]

Comment: You are right, I just need to read but in terms of further using the informations I read. (I need to unpack log files and than get some informations of them.)

Comment: So that doesn't seem like something you need to do in C to me - and if you are the only user of this program, it shouldn't really matter if you use system or popen, but I do agree that popen is more secure.